# XSLT v2.0, xsl:sort with regex instead of substring?

Tags: xslt

I am attempting to sort strings from an XML file with irregular content using xslt 2.0.

The list should be ordered according to the number directly following 'Rep.' and THEN the number directly following 'Nr.', everything else can be ignored (Tit., Bd., etc).

Here are some examples of the strings in the XML:

```
<a>I. HA Rep. 90, Nr. 45203</a>
<a>Rep. 89 Nr. 17750</a>
<a>I. HA Rep. 77, Tit. 500 Nr. 42 Bd. 5</a>
<a>I. HA Rep. 77, Tit. 500 Nr. 43 Adhibendum</a>
<a>I. HA Rep. 77 Tit. 343a Nr. 142 Bd. 7</a>
<a>I. HA Rep. 97 Nr. 5285</a>
```

The list should look like this:

```
<a>I. HA Rep. 77, Tit. 500 Nr. 42 Bd. 5</a>
<a>I. HA Rep. 77, Tit. 500 Nr. 43 Adhibendum</a>
<a>I. HA Rep. 77 Tit. 343a Nr. 142 Bd. 7</a>
<a>Rep. 89 Nr. 17750</a>
<a>I. HA Rep. 90, Nr. 45203</a>
<a>I. HA Rep. 97 Nr. 5285</a>
```

I wrote this in XSLT:

```
<xsl:sort select="concat(format-number(number(substring-before(substring-after(a, 'Rep. '),', Nr.')),'000'),format-number(number(substring-after(a, 'Nr. ')),'0000000000'))" data-type="number" />'
```

This works, but only for the most common case (the first one in the list). I have almost 1000 of these strings so I need regex, but I can't figure out how to use fn:replace, fn:matches or fn:tokenize for this sort. I have tried all of them. fn:match only gives me true or false, fn:replace only allows xpath in the second parameter (i need it in the third), maybe with fn:tokenize?

I have spent hours on this easy problem, I appreciate any hints offered to this novice.

Comment: You could use `xsl:analyze-string` in a user-defined function with `xsl:function` to extract the numbers.

Comment: You do not even need the function, XSLT 2.0 also allows you to put the `xsl:analyze-string` as a child of the `xsl:sort`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:sort select="replace(., '(.*Rep\.\s)(\d+)(.*)', '$2')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
<xsl:sort select="replace(., '(.*Nr\.\s)(\d+)(.*)', '$2')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
```

Comment: What the hey, I did not know you could refer to the second parameter in the third parameter of fn:replace. I kept trying to solve this in one or two lines but had given up. You showed it is possible!!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using two `xsl:sort` with nested `xsl:analyze-string`:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:perform-sort select="a">
            <xsl:sort>
                <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="Rep\.\s*([0-9]+)">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:sequence select="xs:decimal(regex-group(1))"/>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
            </xsl:sort>
            <xsl:sort>
                <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="Nr\.\s*([0-9]+)">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:sequence select="xs:decimal(regex-group(1))"/>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
            </xsl:sort>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```